# Make NetBeans(ant) generate multiple jar files for one project

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

i have a project in netbeans that include two main classes, one starts a client and other starts a server.

I need to create two jar file to wrap into two exe file, one for client and one for server, how can i do this?

Thanks.

NB: im using ant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options:

First, you can overwrite the NetBeans ant target in the project's build.xml in order to create your two jar files. 
How you can do this, is explained in the online help of NetBeans. The chapter is named "Customizing the IDE-Generated Ant Script

But I would recommend to create different projects for each "executable".

Most probably server and client are using some common code, so you'll wind up with three different projects in NetBeans:

1. MyApp Common - contains all classes that are used by server and client
2. MyApp Server - contains everything that you need for the server, includes the project "MyApp Common" as a library
3. MyApp Client - contains everything that you need for the client, includes the project "MyApp Common" as a library.

Then when you build the client or server project, each will generate a separate jar file.

Comment: Thank you, i think create different projects is not a reasonable solution: differents project are hard to maintain, so i prefere to only create different jars. So, can you explain me how to write a build_script to accomplish my target? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why you think different projects are "hard to maintain". You can have them all open at once. You won't even really notice that they are multiple projects

Comment: @blow @a_horse This is an interesting way to approach the problem, but can lead to some issues. Like if you want to run Javadoc on the entire project. Or if you want to keep certain settings consistent between all projects.

Comment: The purpose of having different projects is because it is easy to maintain. Seperating into Common-Server-Client is the most common approach.

Comment: What about project nesting?  i.e. One main project which contains two sub projects with their own Ant builds.  Does NB spaz out with such an arrangement?  I'd like to have a single Ant build file which can kick off all sub-project builds at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two mains in the same jar file. (Only one if you want an executable jar)

To create two jars you need two maven modules/pom.xml

Comment: I know i can add two main at single jar, but i want two jar. Im useing ANT.

Comment: I assumed that since netbeans uses maven by default, that is what you would be using. its been too long since I used ant to say you did this.

Comment: Ant seems to be the default in netbeans even now in the future

Comment: @LenW My confusion may have been that I had only ever seen people use netbeans with maven including myself. i.e. I must have chosen it without thinking about it.