# Netbeans: splitting one project in three (client/server/common)

Tags: java, netbeans

In my self-imposed quest to learn Netbeans, I decided to try out an already existing project of mine.

Using a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768218/make-netbeansant-generate-multiple-jar-files-for-one-project), I tried to make three different projects to host server/client/common portions of my code. I failed at the second one with the message:

```
"Package Folder Already Used in Project"
The following folders that you selected are already used in this or another 
project.
```

Etc., etc. Bottomline: folder used as source in one project, can't be used as source in another one.

---

The problem is, the application *does* use single source folder...

- src/com/.../client/
- src/com/.../common/
- src/com/.../server/

... and I was planning on adding the same folder to each project, filtering needed classes with Includes/Excludes.

What is the kosher way of achieving what I'm trying to do here? (Barring that, *vege* way will do, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each project its own source folder and completely separate them. Then add a project reference for Common to the Client and Server projects so they have access to the compiled class files and documentation. We have a very similar setup for one of our projects.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll settle for this. (Although I'm not exactly happy I can't actually leave the code as-is, in one directory tree..)

Answer (score 2):

I've had something similar and worked around it by using symlinks:

Create folders for each project.
In each project folder, create symlinks to required (common) source folders.

This way, my IDE was satisfied and I was able to work on common source in each project.
Naturally, YMMV.